# Reinstalling curtain rod after wallpapering

Tags: nails, wallpaper

I am having wallpaper hung in a room that has drapes. I'll take the rod/brackets down to have it done but how do I reinstall the brackets if I lose the holes? Should I patch the holes before the wallpaper goes up and re-drill?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

If the old holes are still good, take pictures showing the holes with a tape measure that’s hooked onto something distinctive about the window casing (like a corner). A pic showing distance from the ceiling would help.

Once the wallpaper is on, get to the general area with the pictures and you’ll be able to find the exact location of the old holes by feel.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If the drapes are hanging secure, don't patch and redrill. I've done it two ways. Put the screws back in the holes almost flush with the wall. The wallpaper will go right over them but you'll be able to "feel" them and unscrew them. You could also use a magnet to find them. You could also stick toothpicks in the holes so they barely protrude the wall. They will punch through the wallpaper when it's installed.

Comment: Thank you very much!